# Calculation in SSRS based on Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am trying to create a finance report based on date range parameters selected.  There are 35 hours available each week.  If a person selects 2 weeks in the date parameters we want to calculate 35*2 as total hours available.

Is there a calculation that will help with this?

Comment: It would equate to 7 hours a day available.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the value `7` as a hidden parameter `HoursPerWorkDay` and then do the calculation based on work days between your 2 date parameters.

```
=((DateDiff(DateInterval.day, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Parameters!EndDate.Value) + 1) 
- DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Parameters!StartDate.Value, Parameters!EndDate.Value)*2) 
* Parameters!HoursPerWorkDay.Value
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in?